# Looking for a concurrent data structure checker

Tags: library, c++, code-analysis, debugging, multi-threading

While reading “C++ Concurrency in Action 2nd Edition” by Anthony Williams, I stumbled across a sentence about an automatic tool that verifies concurrent data structures. He said that such tools exist, but didn’t give an example.

I looked around for a bit and found mostly only research papers, though the name “CDSChecker” has appeared multiple times referring to some tool that supposedly can detect bugs from straight analyzing C++ source.

What are some tools/libraries like this used in practice, you could recommend? Could you also perhaps link to a project page or a download, as most of the papers I found had benchmarks of their implementations, but I couldn’t find a place to download them anywhere?